# trying to create a simple text to ascii converter

Tags: javascript, forms, events, button

I have a HTML form:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="????"></input>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var code, chr = 'here';
code = chr.charCodeAt(0);
document.write("The ASCII code of " + chr +" is "+code);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to have a text area in which user/me will put his text (a single letter) and a button which he will click to trigger this event.

Now the problem is how do I make the submit button to submit the whatever is in the text area to:

```
var code, chr = '`here`';
```

Please let me know if there is additional data required.

Comment: 1) Don't use `document.write`. 2) Loop through all characters, to get the char codes. 3) Contain the code in a function, and add that function name to the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: I didn't understood your 2nd point.

Comment: Your current code only shows the character code for the first character (=index **`0`** in `.charCodeAt( 0 )`. If you use a loop, you can see the char codes of your whole input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking forL you need a function that ascii translates input and you need to call that from the button.

I would suggest using something like the following because the calls from the button are all relative you could have 15 such forms on a page and they will all work, plus your actual translation method is kept simple and discrete.

Although with something so simple you could just Drop it inline.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function asciify(txt) {
    return = txt.charCodeAt(0);
}
</script>
<form>
<textarea name="txt_input"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.txt_output.value = asciify(this.form.txt_input.value)"></input>
<textarea name="txt_output"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, made on osx Safari:

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
ASCII:<br>
<textarea id="text" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea><br>
<input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="asciify()">
<br>
<hr>
DEC:<br>
<textarea id="output" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function asciify(){
      var ih = document.getElementById("text").value;
      var out = "";
      for(var i = 0; i < ih.length; i++){
         out=out.concat("<",ih.charAt(i).charCodeAt(0),">");
      }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="subm"/>
<div id="out"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("subm").addEventListener("click", asciify, false);
function asciify(){
    var ih = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    var out = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < ih.length; i++){
        out.push(ih.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = out.join(",")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This uses javascript to add an onclick handler, and supports more than one character